# Flycheck: Reenable automatically disabled checker?

Tags: flycheck

I have slightly tweaked checkers in flycheck so that I can run my code in docker containers. I've tweaked how these settings work, which has temporarily broken my flycheck setup and flycheck has disabled checkers.

[image]

I think I've fixed the bug I want to check how it works. If I remember correctly, to get this working before I would repeatedly close and reopen files to clear flychecks automatic disabled checkers... but this time this feels like a stupid approach.

**How do I clear flychecks automatically disabled checkers?**

## Reading

- https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/1416
- https://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/user/troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning flycheck shows when a checker is automatically disabled explains how to re-enable it:

> Warning (flycheck): Syntax checker ... reported too many errors (...) and is disabled.
> Use ‘M-x customize-variable RET flycheck-checker-error-threshold’ to
> change the threshold or ‘C-u C-c ! x’ to re-enable the checker.

This can also be found in the documentation:

```
To enable a disabled checker again, remove it from flycheck-disabled-checkers or use C-u C-c ! x:

C-u C-c ! x
C-u M-x flycheck-disable-checker

    Prompt for a disabled syntax checker to enable again in the current buffer.
```

(https://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/user/syntax-checkers.html#key-C-c%20!%20x)